# Битрикс24 + cloudpayments

Tags: битрикс24, crm

Простой лендинг, на нем виджет платежной системы от cloudpayments. Оплата курса. Нужно оплату учитывать в битрикс 24 и создавать либо сделку либо заказ. Как лучше это сделать?

Если через битрикс, то я только нашел выставление счета, но там максимум можно сделать регулярные по 1 дню. Но это явно не подходит. А если через личный кабинет cloudpayments, то битрикс не видит оплату. А если включить калбек Check, то вообще оплата не проходит

Answer (score 0):

Может пригодится кому. Решил вопрос через виджет cloudpayments через его калбэк и по api битрекс24